# Why am I getting a LazyInitializationException when using FetchType.LAZY on one Set, but not on the other?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, lazy-initialization

I'm running into quite the peculiar problem here; it seems like some Sets do load lazily, but others don't, but the underlying class layouts are exactly the same:

I have 4 classes, in a Spring-boot Hibernate mapping:

These is the top-leveled class, **Event**:

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    // Getters, setters, etc. are omitted.

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "event", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Question.class)
    private Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "event", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Participant.class)
    private Set<Participant> participants = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "event", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Run.class)
    private Set<Run> runs = new HashSet<>();

}
```

These are the 3 classes that are linked to this very event root-node class:

**Question**:

```
@Entity
public class Question {

    // Getters, setters, etc. are omitted.

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Event event;
}
```

**Participant**:

```
@Entity
public class Participant {

    // Getters, setters, etc. are omitted.

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Event event;
}
```

**Run**:

```
@Entity
public class Run {

    // Getters, setters, etc. are omitted.

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Event event;
}
```

Of course, there are JPA-related empty constructors, other constructors, a lot of Hibernate/JPA tags and more underlying relations, but I'm convinced these are not making the difference here. Problems started occurring upon introducing the `Set<Run>` variable to the **Event** class.

Running the program, and creating an object of type **Event** adding events and all goes fine, but creating a new **Run** object and trying to add it to the `Event.runs` field gives me the following error in JUnit testing:

**On a call to `event.getRuns().add(<a new 'Run' object>)`:**

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.ps.model.orm.Event.runs, could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:576)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:215)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:555)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.add(PersistentSet.java:202)
at com.ps.HibernateTestApplicationTests.testRunCreation(HibernateTestApplicationTests.java:88)
at com.ps.HibernateTestApplicationTests.testAllTheThings(HibernateTestApplicationTests.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Lazy instantiation just seems broken to me at this point. When I change the `FetchType.LAZY` of the **@OneToMany** tag for `Event.runs` to `FetchType.EAGER`, the program executes as it is supposed to, but I can't for the life of me figure out why LAZY isn't working here while it is for the other classes, as their structure is nearly identical.

The others work, both `LAZY` *and* `EAGER`, while this one doesn't, and I am truly not seeing the difference in mapping or anything here, so even though I'm now just using the `EAGER` type, instead of `LAZY`, I know this is discouraged and would like to know if there's anything going on I might have looked over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the stacktrace tells you the problem -

> could not initialize proxy - no Session

just ensure that `event.getRuns().add(<a new 'Run' object>)` is called within a transaction where the Session is still available.
if using Spring just annotate the method with `@Transactional`

Something like this

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething(){

Event event= // get Event from DB ;
event.getRuns.add(//new Run);
//some other stuff
}
```

Comment: Annotating the main test method with `@Transactional` fixed it, indeed. I swear I had tried that on other methods, but I guess I skipped this one. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.I have solved this adding following codes to my **web.xml** file.I hope it will help you ;)

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```